# Как нарисовать какой-либо элемент или кнопку поверх MPV встроенного в QWidget (python-mpv+pyside6)

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside6, qgraphicsview

Я использую [эту](https://github.com/jaseg/python-mpv) библиотеку (***python-mpv***) и *`PySide6`* для создания виджета с  MPV (QWidget) на python. 
Я хочу нарисовать кнопку (или что либо ещё например `QLabel`?) поверх `QWidget` (того самого, в который встроен плеер).

Как я могу это сделать? Я пытался нарисовать кнопку поверх виджета, но как только плеер начинает воспроизведение кнопка пропадает. Возможно ли поместить что либо поверх плеера?

**UPD**:
Я нашел что должен скорее всего использовать *OpenGl* для этого.:https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv-examples/blob/master/libmpv/README.md

Как я могу реализовать это используя *PySide6* или *PyQT5*?

**Мой код:**

```py
import os

from PySide6 import QtWidgets


os.environ['PATH'] = os.path.dirname(__file__) #you need to place mpv-2.dll (or mpv-1.dll) in folder with project
import mpv
import sys

from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
from PySide6.QtCore import *

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        if not Form.objectName():
            Form.setObjectName(u"Form")
        Form.resize(780, 477)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QRect(30, 430, 75, 24))

        self.retranslateUi(Form)

        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
    # setupUi

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"Form", None))
        self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("Form", u"PushButton", None))
    # retranslateUi

class PlayerWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PlayerWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.retranslateUi(self)


class Test(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.container = PlayerWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.container)
        self.container.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DontCreateNativeAncestors)
        self.container.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NativeWindow)
        player = mpv.MPV(wid=str(int(self.container.winId())),
                vo='gpu',
                log_handler=print,
                loglevel='debug', ytdl=True)
        player.play('test1.mkv')  # положите любое тестовое видео в папку
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# This is necessary since PyQT stomps over the locale settings needed by libmpv.
# This needs to happen after importing PyQT before creating the first mpv.MPV instance.
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'C')
win = Test()
win.show()
win.resize(1280, 720)
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Библиотека **`python-mpv`** требует для запуска **`mpv-2.dll`** скачать его вы можете [здесь](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mpv-player-windows/files/libmpv/). (sourceforge)

Answer (score 1):

Я не могу попробовать ваш пример.

Если использовать:

- Класс [**QMediaPlayer**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#details) позволяет воспроизводить источник мультимедиа и
- [**QGraphicsView**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html) с [**QGraphicsVideoItem**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsvideoitem.html),

то получается что-то такое:

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtMultimedia, QtMultimediaWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class GraphicsPixmapItem(QGraphicsPixmapItem):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GraphicsPixmapItem, self).__init__(parent)
        
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(f'QGraphicsPixmapItem: {event.pos()}')
        super().mousePressEvent(event)


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.gv = QtWidgets.QGraphicsView(self.scene)

        self.videoitem = QtMultimediaWidgets.QGraphicsVideoItem()
        self.videoitem.setSize(QSizeF(640, 480))
        self.scene.addItem(self.videoitem)

        self.pic = GraphicsPixmapItem(self.videoitem)
        self.pic.setPixmap(QPixmap('Ok.png').scaled(40, 40))
        self.pic.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable | QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.pic.setOffset(20, 20)
        
        self.text = QGraphicsTextItem(self.videoitem)
        self.text.setHtml('<h1>Hello PyQt5</h1>')   
        self.text.setDefaultTextColor(QColor(66, 222, 88)) 
        self.text.setPos(100, 380)        

        self._player = QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer(self, QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self._player.stateChanged.connect(self.on_stateChanged)
        self._player.setVideoOutput(self.videoitem)

# ----------- установите свое ------------------------> vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv <--------
        file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "Samonastrojka.avi")

        self._player.setMedia(QtMultimedia.QMediaContent(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(file)))
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Play")
        button.clicked.connect(self._player.play)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.gv)
        lay.addWidget(button)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.State)
    def on_stateChanged(self, state):
        if state == QtMultimedia.QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.gv.fitInView(self.videoitem, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(670, 540)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению такая реализация не подходит мне по 1 причине, функции QMediaPlayer весьма ограничены, к примеру он не поддерживает субтитры и в инекоторых аспектах невозможен в управлении, в любом случае спасибо за ответ я думаю кому либо данная реализация поможет.